# The output of a python script

Tags: python

So I am trying to debug some Python code that I am running, because for some reason when I run the code in a command line it works perfectly, but when I make it a `.py` file and run it that way it fails.

The output is in a Windows Commander window, and it disappears before I can read it.

Is there a way to see what this output is?

Comment: use `import time` and `time.sleep(100)` to check your program.

Answer (score 0):

Open a windows commander, and then go to the dir where a.py is, run "python a.py", it will not disappear!